# VueJS CLI Webpack static folder not working when in subfolder

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

i'm using the vuejs cli webpack template.
My URL's are not working properly, for example:

```
<link rel="..." href="/static/img/favicons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
```

This works fine on my development server, but not on my production server -> (404 file not found).

And if i try this on my dev server:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/static/php/process.php',
        data: term_formData
    })
```

(main.js), url not working.(404 file not found)

I already changed the webpack option: assetsPublicPath.

The Webpack config/index.js file:

```
  build: {
    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
```

> assetsPublicPath: '/vueapp/dist/',

```
    ...
```

**Production server:  http://localhost/vueapp/dist/

Development server:  http://localhost:8080/**

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: `assetsSubDirectory: './static'`. This happens because you haven't placed your application in the web root, which the template assumes. The other solution is to make  `vueapp/dist` your web root in your Apache/Nginx config.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `assetsSubDirectory: './static'`. This happens because you haven't placed your application in the web root, which the template assumes. The other solution is to make `vueapp/dist` your web root in your Apache/Nginx config.